# Something similar to Counter in a Django table

Tags: python, django, sqlite, group-by, counter

I have a table in sqlite3 with a column that tells me the winners of a game:
(computer = 1, human = 2, tie = 0)

The model (I'm working on django) is something like this, at least the necessary part:

```
class GameWinners(models.Model):
    CHOICES = [(0, 'Draw'), (1, 'Computer'), (2, 'Human')]
    game_winner = models.IntegerField(choices=CHOICES)
```

I would like to obtain a dictionary that counts me the times that each one has won or the ties.
something similar to Counter from collections:

`games = {0: 27, 1: 125, 2: 170}`

I know that I could do it this way:

```
tie = GameWinners.objects.filter(game_winner=0).count()
computer = GameWinners.objects.filter(game_winner=1).count()
human = GameWinners.objects.filter(game_winner=2).count()
```

`games = {0: tie, 1: computer, 2: human}`

But I guess there must be a better way to do it.

**Update**

Although the code works in the example that I have given, it has to filter the table three times to count the different elements, and in the future it will be a fairly large table.

While waiting for an answer, i have also tried with (which I think is the solution I am looking for):

```
query = "SELECT COUNT(game_winner) FROM core_gamewinner GROUP_BY game_winner"
games = GameWinners.objects.raw(query)
```

Which as @Tarquinius suggests, is a more efficient way. But it returns me:

```
OperationalError at /
near "game_winner": syntax error
```

Comment: If the code is working and you're simply want to have a code review, you better ask this question on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It works, but it's not what I'm looking for. I have only put it so that it is understood what I want to achieve.

Comment: @colidyre, the question would need quite a bit of work before it's suited to [codereview.se]. You could have pointed the asker at [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778), as some things are done differently over there - e.g. we need to see complete code in context rather than SO-style [mcve], and a good description of the *purpose* of the code, with a title that simply says what the code *is for* (the question is always, "_How can I improve this?_").

Comment: Thank you  for the hint @TobySpeight. I was not aware of this.

Answer (score 1):

From a django point of view there is not much of improvement you can do. Your options are to do `len(queryset)` or `queryset.count()`.

The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#count) says that if you just want to have the count, using the method `count()` on the queryset is the most efficient thing to do.
Whereas if you also want to retrieve the model instances from the queryset you should go for `len(queryset)` because this does not require a further database lookup like `.filter().count()` would do.

If you like oneliner more than multiple lines you could go for:

```py
tie, computer, human = [GameWinners.objects.filter(game_winner=num).count() for num in (0,1,2)]
```

But I guess that was not the aim of your question.

Some more background: The most efficient call would be a plain SQL command, right? This is utilized by the `count()` method as you can read in linked documentation. So since `count()` is a wrapper for `SELECT COUNT(*)` it is pretty straight forward to use and performant.

Answer (score 1):

At the end I had a typo, `GROUP_BY => GROUP BY`. The best way I have found is this:

```
sql_query = "SELECT id, game_winner, count(game_winner) AS total FROM core_gamewinner GROUP BY game_winner"
rawquery = GameWinner.objects.raw(sql_query)
games = {_.game_winner: _.total for _ in rawquery}
```